# Nsstring data isnt retianed after passing a controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, viewcontroller

My NSString data is being lost when I transfer from view controller 1 to view controller 2 then viewcontroller 3. However when I transfer from viewcontroller 1 to viewcontroller 3 it works. So the way I am switching from viewcontroller 1 to view controller 2 is causing me to lose the nsstring data for some reason. I will post my code below, but my guess is I will need to do something in view controller 2.

viewcontroller1

```
-(void)button{
    stringEntered=textField.text;
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
    vc2.string = [[NSString stringWithString:textField.text] retain];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES]; 
}
```

viewcontroller 2

```
-(void)button{
    ViewController3 *vc3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

Viewcontroller3

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
```

Comment: How are you declaring "string" in your controllers? Also, there's no need to use either stringWithString or stringWithFormat since textField.text and string are already strings.

Comment: You don't have any code that would pass the string to vc3 in the button method in vc2, so why would you expect it get passed?

Comment: So there isn't any easy way to retain it in second view controller? Basically Im guessing you have to pass data from vc 1 to vc2 then pass data to vc3

Comment: Yes, you need to pass it to a property in vc2, then pass that value to a property in vc3.

Comment: God, I now it isn't a good idea to use nsuserdefault, but man it sure makes things easier.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use NSUserDefaults for passing values between controllers.

Comment: @TwoFace it should be far more of a hassel to use defaults if your program is designed right.

Comment: I have a question is this a good way to pass a lot of data between view controllers?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish by passing this string along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewcontroller 3 .h file write below line

```
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSString *string;
```

and synthesize it in .m file

```
@synthesize string;
```

now in viewcontroller 2

```
-(void)button{
    ViewController3 *vc3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
vc3.string =string;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

Make sure you have define string in vc2 properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Macro.h file and create AppDelegate var like this

extern AppDelegate *delegate;

In AppDelegate declare like this

AppDelegate *delegate;

and in appdelegate:DidfinishlaunchingwithOptions:

do like this

delegate = [[UIApplciaiton sharedApplication]delegate];

and then declare one NSString *string in appdelegate and create iVar and property,synthesize it and make it a copy type property and

in viewcontroller1

assign delegate.string = @"";

in viewcontroller you can access like

NSString *string1 = delegate.string;

If you get any error saying delegate not found in viewcontroller1 or viewcontroller2 then import appdelegate and macro.h file in viewcontroller1 and viewcontroller2

Cheers:)